# How to declare blocks using Swift in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, block, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am trying to convert my Objective C source code to swift, I have searched alot to change syntax for Blocks.

Here is my Objective C code that I want to switch to Swift :

class.h file :

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^tapBlock)(CGFlagsCell *);

+ (NSString *)cellIdentifier;
```

Class.m file :

```
self.tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didTapCell)];

- (void)didTapCell {
    self.tapBlock(self);
}
```

Comment: I have converted the class method as                                                      class func cellIdentifier() -> String {
        return "yourValue"
    }    please help me for the rest. Thanks!

Comment: I don't get what you want exactly .

Comment: @ BoilingLime I want to convert my above objective C code to Swift for Blocks. My Objective C code is : @property (nonatomic, copy) void (^tapBlock)(CGFlagsCell *);

Comment: If anyone can't help me, so why you guys are doing down vote.... If you are thinking that my question is not good for StackOverFlow.. then tell me the reason..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Swift, blocks, functions and closures are the same thing, they have the same signature and are interchangeable.

So this would give you something like this

```
var  tapBlock: CGFlagsCell -> Void
```

You can add parenthesis around the parameter (optional if there is only one, recommended if there are multiple input parameters) and around the return type (optional):

```
var tapBlock: (CGFlagsCell) -> (Void)
```

Comment: Thanks alot @AliSoftware for your help... It's working fine now, Can you please give me some idea for UITapGestureRecognizer if possible, As this is my custom UITableViewCell.

Comment: Thanks again @AliSoftware... But I don't know why down vote, anyway this will help to other programmers.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Define a closure a variable of your class :

`var tapBlock: (parameterTypes) -> (returnType)`

Swift Closures are self-contained blocks of functionality that can be passed around and used in your code. Closures in Swift are similar to blocks Objective-C